# Disappearing apollonian-gasket

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

[Apollonian gasket](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349032/apollonian-gasket) disappeared although it had a detailed answer by *achille hui*. Anyone knows the reason?

Comment: Self-deleted by OP. (Not clear why.)

Comment: @quid: I suspect it is related to his later question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348950/generalizing-the-given-equation.

Comment: Now [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349108/find-radius-of-circle) appears.

Comment: That self-deleted question originates from an [online contest](http://www.codechef.com/JULY15/problems/NTHCIR). No wonder my effort get wasted.

Comment: @achillehui: I wish Math SE would have more severe consequences for cheaters. It is clearly unfair to get any help for a contest unless explicitly allowed, no matter how small the help. But all that is done here is that the question is locked, which is terribly inadequate.

Comment: I guess that this question should be locked, or something, at least for a while. @achillehui: Please consider deleting your answer for the time being.

Comment: Indeed, it is now locked. @achille's answer is (temporarily) deleted. Shame on the OP (of that question).

Comment: @mixedmath: What about the one that *Mark* mentioned?

Comment: @mixedmath: Maybe it's worth cross referencing the other questions by the OP against this contest.

Comment: @user21820 someone flag them, we'll handle them.

Comment: @mixedmath As discussed here in the past, deleting the answer is not a good resolution,  since it gives the  particpant(s) who have seen the answer an unfair advantage over those who have not.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Based on the current contest, it's arguable either way. If it stays there, more participants can cheat by finding it online, and they will be more likely to do so since it is not them who posted the question. If it does not stay there, it is true that the asker has cheated already, but at least we can hope that it discourages the asker from doing it again if there is community consensus that it is unacceptable behaviour. Leaving it there may convey (like it or not) that we cannot really be bothered by cheating.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Of course, more should be done, and I have always thought that if we are stringent in what we consider questions that show work, and guide askers to the correct understanding without simply giving straight answers to the actual question, we effectively would weed out a lot of such cheaters because it would take them sufficient effort to learn that they would be too lazy to attempt to get answers here. This is just my opinion though, which is not the norm; most answerers don't even guide the asker to discover the solution, but rather just spoon-feed them.

Comment: @user21820 You should read the old discussions to better understand all of the issues. I highly doubt that such actions will discourage future questions of this sort (they haven't yet in a few years). But the current resolution will no doubt discourage students who discover that the possible "winner" has received outside help. It seems that the only fair resolution is to remove the question from the contest, since there is no way to know how many participants have seen the solution. IMO, it is contests, not MSE, that require better design to deal with these issues.

Comment: Undeleting the answer is not a good resolution either, since it gives the participant(s) who will see the answer an unfair advantage over those who will not.

Comment: @Hurkyl There is no perfect resolution, But I buy the (many, strong) arguments for not-deleting once an answer has appeared.

Comment: @Bill: "Deleting the answer is not a good resolution" is not an example of such..

Comment: @Hurkly These arguments have already been made many times before on meta. so there is little point to repeating them again here.

Comment: @Bill: That sounds quite reasonable, once you delete your comments starting from "Deleting the answer is not a good resolution", I will delete my responses to them, and we can ask user21820 to do so as well.

Comment: @BillDubuque: `IMO, it is contests, not MSE, that require better design to deal with these issues.` Agreed, but that does not diminish our own responsibility to do what we can, however little that is. It is just like if we observe someone cheating during an examination but the invigilators and everyone else do not. We cannot say we shouldn't do anything. I said earlier that it's arguable whether we should lock the question and hide the answers (though I think it is usually the right thing to do), but I also hinted that the main problem is our general attitude in answering questions.

Comment: @BillDubuque: By the way, I think I had read most of the previous discussions on this. If you notice, in my question and comments I wasn't the one who brought up the locking of the question and the hiding of the answers. Later I was simply responding to your comment with my own views, which you are free to reject on your own grounds.